# when requesting download, the file stays at 0 bytes?

Tags: java, buffer

hello well i wrote some code to download a file and put it in the desktop.

but whenever it starts downloading, it just stays at 0 bytes, why is that?

here's my code :

```
    private void addToDesktop() throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL("theurl");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    InputStream inputstream = connection.getInputStream();
    FileSystemView filesys = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    filesys.getHomeDirectory();
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedoutputstream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filesys.getHomeDirectory() + "/client2.jar")));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while(bytesRead == inputstream.read(buffer))
    {
        bufferedoutputstream.write(buffer, 0 ,1000);
    }
    bufferedoutputstream.flush();
    bufferedoutputstream.close();
    inputstream.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29), the `read(byte[] buffer)` returns the amount of bytes read. If there are no more bytes to be read, then -1 is returned.

The problem seems to lie here: `while(bytesRead == inputstream.read(buffer))`. Since `bytesRead` will have a value of 0 however, the `.read` method will yield 1024. Changing it to something like so should work: `while(inputstream.read(buffer) != -1)`

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
int bytesRead = 0;

while(bytesRead == inputstream.read(buffer))
{
   ...
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
while(0 == inputstream.read(buffer))
{
   ...
}
```

That condition will generally be false, and the loop will never execute. You probably meant something more like this:

```
int bytesRead;

while((bytesRead = inputstream.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
   ...
}
```

The moral here is: Mind your `=` vs. `==` in these types of statements.

---

By the way: You are writing 1000 bytes to the output file every time through the loop no matter how many bytes were read. You actually just want to be writing what was read (sometimes `read()` may not read the full buffer, especially at the end of the file if the buffer is larger than the remaining data). You'd want to do this instead:

```
while((bytesRead = inputstream.read(buffer)) > 0)
{ 
    bufferedoutputstream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: @Boolena Is your URL really "theurl"...? If so, that would certainly explain it. Try adding some temporary print-outs to your code to trace through what is happening (e.g. in the loop to print the number of bytes read each time, etc.).

Comment: @Boolena Are you sure the URL is valid? Are you sure there's actually data at that URL (try loading it in a browser to verify)? Is an `IOException` being raised that you are ignoring at a higher level (and so it's silent)?

Comment: hey it actually worked, but it downloaded more than needed and the jar is corrupt?

Comment: in the bufferedoutputstream.write(buffer, 0 , 1024); what does the 1024 specify? my actual jar file is 3.70 mb and the one this app is downloading is 3.79

Comment: @Boolena See [`BufferedOutputStream.write`](http://bit.ly/1i90dcS). It is the number of bytes to write. Check out the bit I added at the end of my answer.